# Ingreso de datos por phpmyadmin no reconoce cotejamiento UTF-8

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, utf-8, idioma

Hay veces en las que ingreso informacion a mi pagina web por phpmyadmin, haciendo una nueva insercion, pero cuando actualizo mi pagina web para ver los cambios, me muestra algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los cotejamientos para cada campo se encuentran en uft8_spanish_ci, tal como se aprecia en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe a que se debe este problema? incluso tengo las etiquetas

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

en la pagina, pero aun asi no lo reconoce..

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Por que el Carácter inspector (�) aparece en algunos datos obtenidos de la Base de Datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/59489/por-que-el-car%c3%a1cter-inspector-aparece-en-algunos-datos-obtenidos-de-la-base). La codificación tiene que  ser verificada en varios niveles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade esto en tu fichero PHP despues de hacer la conexion a la base de datos.

`mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");`

Donde $conexion es tu variable de conexion a la BBDD